# Using casefold() with dataframe Column Names and .contains method

Tags: python, pandas

How do I look for instances in the dataframe where the 'Campaign' column contains b0.

I would like to not alter the dataframe values but instead just view them as if they were lowercase.

```
df.loc.str.casefold()[df['Campaign'].str.casefold().contains('b0')]
```

I recently inquired about doing this in the instance of matching a specific string like below, but what I am asking above I am finding to be more difficult.

```
df['Record Type'].str.lower() == 'keyword'
```

Comment: Does `df[df['Campaign'].str.casefold().contains('b0')]` work?

Comment: no, it gives a ''Series' object has no attribute 'contains'. ' error.    But that also does not address the need to view the column heading itself as if it were lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df.loc[df['Campaign'].str.contains('b0',case=False)]
```

Comment: this works for dealing with the 'b0' portion, but how would I reference the column heading as a lower-case instance of it, without actually changing it to lowercase?

Comment: @anarchocaps you do not need to change since we turn the case sensitive to False

Comment: when I change the code from 'Campaign' to 'campaign', I get 'KeyError: 'campaign'

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to create a subset of the dataframe:

`df_subset = df[(df[('Campaign')].str.casefold().str.contains('b0', na=False))]`